# Intra-Provincial Waterway Laws

Tags: canada, federalism, water

My question is related to boats in an intra- provincial waterway. Waterways are federal, but Ottawa, Ontario and Gatineau Quebec share the river system. As a commercial vessel what laws would regulate the sale of alcohol on the water? Let's trow in. some marine law while we are at it. Cruise ships and small commercial boats are regulated by which province?